# How to implement Symfony Form choice field that varies by context and instance?

Tags: symfony

The use case is generally an entity association (ManyToOne or ManyToMany) where the target entity may be archived by the user. If the association is already established it should be present in the choices regardless of whether it is archived or not. Otherwise, archived entities should be excluded from the list.

In addition, this behaviour should be configurable. For instance, a filter form will want the same field but even archived values should be shown in the list.

The sorting and grouping of the values should be configurable, and not through the constructor because that will typically be used by the dependency injection service.

Caching will be largely disabled because the options vary by form instance, but that is acceptable. I am unsure if multiple queries or post-filtering of a broad query is likely to be more efficient.

The field should also be standalone, so the parent form should not be required to specify `*_SET_DATA` listeners.

**Update** See https://gist.github.com/ryancastle/466f861348249cf335eb for typical example.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking for but form events can be used to modify choices based on the current entity: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: Yeah. I've been using Symfony for 5 years. I was just curious to know if anyone had a solution to this problem.

Comment: I have read this 4 times and I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.  What is the bigger picture here?

If you have orders and the orders were tagged.  You want to be able to show tagged content even though its been previously archived?

Comment: Yes. If you exclude all archived entities in the `query_builder`, then older objects that reference those entities will not be able to render the choice field because the form data for that field is no longer in the choice list.

Comment: It seems to me that there isn't enough info here.  Why wouldn't a simple call back to the database for the data your are looking for solve the situation?  Why is front loading all the data onto the form the correct solution?

Comment: When you define 'query_builder' the form data isn't available. You can't modify the configuration options of form builder fields in the form listeners - only add new individual instances of form fields. Which is the solution all the Symfony docs use, except that it requires each parent form referencing the selector to specify these listeners. In one project we have this exact issue with the Contact selector, the Product selector and the Job Code selector. The can all be archived, but must still always display in the selectors of old owning entity forms.

Comment: Like B Rad I have no idea what you are trying to do.  Your gist seems unrelated to your question.  However, you can indeed modify existing form elements inside of a listener.  Listeners are not limited to only creating new form fields.  But again, it's not clear if this is what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'll close the question.